# Assign task to process initiator in Interstage BPM

Tags: interstage

In Interstage BPM how do I assign a task to the user who started the Process Instance?

I looked at using the Assign Task Action but it doesn't have anything for using the process initiator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Role Actions of the Activity that you want to assign, you need to add two BPM Actions:

1) Workload Balancing Actions : Get Process Initiator - 
This gets the name of the initiator. Set the Target UDA to be a STRING UDA like "initiator".

2) Workload Balancing Actions : Assign Task to User - 
This assigns the task to a user. Set the selector to "V" and select your "initiator" UDA that holds the name of the Process Instance initiator from the first action.